# exp:channel:categories - category_group not working

Tags: categories

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="list">
    {exp:channel:categories 
    parent_only="no" 
    show_empty="no" 
    style="linear" 
    category_group="{if segment_1 == "cave"}3{/if}{if segment_1 == "clothing"}7{/if}{if segment_1 == "accessories"}8{/if}{if segment_1 == "brands"}2{/if}"}
        <li>
          <article>
            <a href="/{segment_1}/category/{category_url_title}">
              {category_image}
              <h2>{category_name}</h2>
            </a>
          </article>
        </li>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
  </ul>
```

But category_group doesn't seem to be working, I've tried the segment names in both double quotes and single quote and it still doesn't work any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you just set category_group="3" parameter? Also what version of EE are you using? I assume the categories in question aren't empty (try show_empty="yes")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some days ago, I found a bug on parsing adjacent conditionals:

```
{if segment_1 == "foo"}{/if}{if segment_1 == [...]
```

I just had to separate the conditionals:

```
{if segment_1 == "foo"}{/if}
{if segment_1 == [...]
```

So, please, try this:

```
<ul class="list">
    {exp:channel:categories 
    parent_only="no" 
    show_empty="no" 
    style="linear" 
    {if segment_1 == "cave"}category_group="3"{/if}
    {if segment_1 == "clothing"}category_group="7"{/if}
    {if segment_1 == "accessories"}category_group="8"{/if}
    {if segment_1 == "brands"}category_group="2"{/if}
    }
        <li>
          <article>
            <a href="/{segment_1}/category/{category_url_title}">
              {category_image}
              <h2>{category_name}</h2>
            </a>
          </article>
        </li>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Seems we have the same bug, this works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try Low's seg2cat and use {segment_n_category_group_id}
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs

Answer (score 1):

Christy's solution is a good one for sure.

But just in case your segments don't match the category group `url_title` exactly, try an embed or Stash. Here's the embed version.

In your current template, replace your current tag pair with this:

```
{embed="group/name_your_new_embed_template"
    cat="{if segment_1 == "cave"}3{/if}{if segment_1 == "clothing"}7{/if}{if segment_1 == "accessories"}8{/if}{if segment_1 == "brands"}2{/if}"
}
```

Then, in `group/name_your_new_embed_template` put a similar version of current tag pair, that's reads the values being sent for the `cat` parameter:

```
<ul class="list">
  {exp:channel:categories 
    parent_only="no" 
    show_empty="no" 
    style="linear" 
    category_group="{embed:cat}"}
    <li>
      <article>
        <a href="/{segment_1}/category/{category_url_title}">
          {category_image}
          <h2>{category_name}</h2>
        </a>
      </article>
    </li>
  {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```